# Sql server get database permissions by name

Tags: sql-server

We can get permissions by `sp_helprotect` in a specific database. Then how to get permissions of a specific database, for example `master` or `tempdb`?

I have tried this statement right by mysel:

```
SELECT major_id, minor_id, grantor_principal_id, grantee_principal_id, permission_name, pr1.name as GRANTEE, pr2.name as GRANTOR, pr2.create_date, pr2.modify_date 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions where class = 4) as pe
JOIN sys.database_principals AS pr1
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr1.principal_id
JOIN sys.database_principals AS pr2
    ON pe.grantor_principal_id = pr2.principal_id
```

But the major id is 0, so I can't get the permission exist on which object.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx) for `sys.database_permissions` states that:

> Returns a row for every permission or column-exception permission in the database. For columns, there is a row for every permission that is different from the corresponding object-level permission. If the column permission is the same as the corresponding object permission, there will be no row for it and the actual permission used will be that of the object.

So what this means is that your query will return the permissions only for the context of the database in which you are running it. What you are currently doing though is to filter with permissions that exist on Database Principals ( the `class = 4` part of your query). If you want database objects (such as tables, stored procedures etc) you should also include 1 in your class `WHERE` clause.

Edit 1: To get the permissions of tempdb or master you can run the query twice, using:

```
USE master;
GO
/* Your query here that will return the permissions for master */
USE tempdb;
GO
/* Your query here that will return the permissions for master */
```

Edit 2: If you want a single query you can use this one:

```
SELECT major_id, minor_id, grantor_principal_id, grantee_principal_id,   permission_name, pr1.name as GRANTEE, pr2.name as GRANTOR, pr2.create_date, pr2.modify_date , 'master' as db
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM master.sys.database_permissions where class = 4) as pe
INNER JOIN master.sys.database_principals AS pr1
   ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr1.principal_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.database_principals AS pr2
   ON pe.grantor_principal_id = pr2.principal_id
UNION ALL 
SELECT major_id, minor_id, grantor_principal_id, grantee_principal_id, permission_name, pr1.name as GRANTEE, pr2.name as GRANTOR, pr2.create_date, pr2.modify_date , 'tempdb' as db
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.database_permissions where class = 4) as pe
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.database_principals AS pr1
   ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr1.principal_id
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.database_principals AS pr2
   ON pe.grantor_principal_id = pr2.principal_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, so If I want to get every database(master, tempdb) permissions, What should I do, I am try my best, but can't get the good solution, I always try class = 0

Comment: You want one query to return the permission of every database?

Comment: No, I can get table, column, user, roler's permission , Now just want to get the permissions of master or tempdb, the database_level permissions

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully answer your question!

Comment: So I write the query statement is right? But I get empty result set. So do I need to grant something to master or temp to make result set have more? And I want to write some statement like "grant some perms to database_name(master)" , but I can't find any statetment like this.

Comment: I want to make some faked data to make the query show sth.

Comment: I would recommend to firstly omit the `class = 4`. Just use     
    `SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.database_permissions` in your query and see if it returns something.

Comment: whatever I use which database, I am get the same result set.

Comment: So man, do you have any idea about it, may be not use this statements.  Or do you know how to assignment any permissions to one database that I can simulate this situation.