# How to get column_privileges's protecttype with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We can get table permissions with

```
EXEC sp_helprotect
```

and it returns Grantee, Grantor and protecttype.

Then I need to get column permissions, so I use

```
EXEC sp_column_privileges @table_name = yy, @column_name = xx
```

This query returns Grantee and Grantor but no protecttype or object_id (then I can use it and `sp_column_privileges` table to get the protecttype). Is there anybody who can give me some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get table/column permissions in one go using sys.fn_my_permissions. Here's the firehose query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [sys].[objects] AS [o]
CROSS APPLY [sys].[fn_my_permissions]([o].[name], 'object') AS [fmp]
```

If you're interested in more filtering (e.g. you only want permissions for a subset of objects), you can put a where clause on the query (e.g. `where o.name = '«your object name here»'`)

Comment: For example, database: master, table: test, column: id. How to get the id column's permissions. I am not see the type of the sys.objects include column type.

Comment: When you run the above on something that has columns, the column permissions will be returned as part of the result set. Anything that has a non-null `subentity_name` is a column.

Comment: thanks, But where is the Grantee, Grantor, Protecttype of every column's permission. I need to more detail.

Comment: And there is another question about get Database(master, tempdb)'s permission: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339632/sql-server-get-database-permissions-by-name , can you help me again, thanks for advance : )

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better served by querying the security DMVs directly. Take a look in sys.database_permissions and sys.setver_permissions.

Comment: Is the sys.database_permissions's state_desc == protecttype?? And If I want to get database(master, tempdb) permission, just filter (class = 4),  right?